# Load HTML From another File

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know that is there a way in codeigniter to write some data in ahtml file from the controller and then get that html from that file in the controller.

```
$data["messages"] = $this->message_view->getParticularMessage($this->input->post('id'))
$data["users"] = $this->user_view->getAllUsers()
write_file('/messages/panel.tpl', $data)
$string = read_file('/messages/panel.tpl');
error_log(print_r($string , true));
echo json_encode(array('value'=> $string));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet

Comment: @Nehal I tried to use the read_file and write_file function of codeigniter but those are also not working

Comment: Add some code that you have tried, so we can rather sort out your problem

Comment: @Nehal I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

To Write  file in codeigniter:

```
$this->load->helper('file');

$data = 'Some file data';
    if ( ! write_file('/messages/panel.tpl', $data))
    {
            echo 'Unable to write the file';
    }
    else
    {
            echo 'File written!';
    }
```

And to load html file use this:

```
$this->load->view('/messages/panel.tpl');
```

Comment: I know about this I have loaded the helper to but that doesn't works either